# efficient way to remove empty div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `<div contenteditable="true">`, when I press enter to newline with empty input, it will generate `<div><br></div>`.
But I just want to remove it from beginning and at the end.

For example:

> `<div contenteditable="true">`
>
> `<div><br></div>` i want to remove this
>
> abc
>
> `<div><br></div>` remain
>
> 1234
>
> `<div><br></div>` i want to remove this
>
> `<div><br></div>` i want to remove this
>
> `</div>`

```
for(var x = item.length - 1 ; x >= 0 ; x--){
   if($(item[x]).html() == "<br>"){
      $(item[x]).remove();
   }else{
      break;
   }
}

for(var x = 0; x <= item.length-1 ; x++){
   if($(item[x]).html() == "<br>"){
      $(item[x]).remove();
   }else{
      break;
   }
}
```

Currently I'm using two looping to remove it, But I'm looking a better way to filter it.
Anyone can guide me?

Thanks.

Comment: On what action you want to remove them? any `click event`, `blur event` etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually achieve it with `while` loop instead of `for` loop. You need to store the reference for `first` and `last` child of the `contenteditable` `div` and manipulate it with `while` loop. Detailed explanation in comments around the code.

```js
$('.remove').on('click', function() {
  var firstChild = $('div[contenteditable] div:first');
  var lastChild = $('div[contenteditable] div:last');
  //store the reference for first and last child of the contenteditable div
  while(firstChild.html()=="<br>")//remove all the element's until firstchild's html!="<br>" i.e. is not empty
  {
   firstChild.remove();//remove it
   firstChild= $('div[contenteditable] div:first'); //again store the reference to new first child after remove
  }
  //same goes with last child
  while(lastChild.html()=="<br>")
  {
   lastChild.remove();
   lastChild= $('div[contenteditable] div:last');
  }
})
```

```css
div[contenteditable] {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true">

</div>
<button type="button" class="remove">Remove unwanted</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, im fresh graduate, still learning code in different method and the better way  :D

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a div which is empty..(Your question states that)....

This may help.....

```
$("div:empty").remove();
```

This code removes div that are empty...If thats what You wanted this could help

Comment: but I only want to remove empty div before the text, and after the last text.